# Word for when you try to do something to make someone feel better

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, synonyms

For example, if I had a bad day at work,  and my best friend wants to cheer me up so she does something for me, what verb or noun can I use instead of “cheer up”? I’m looking for a word where someone actually does something tangible for the person, more than just emotionally supporting the person. I have looked up information on thesaurus.com and Cambridge and I don’t think I’m looking for “assuage” or “soothe” because I want a word that means I actually went out of my way or actively did something to help my friend’s day be better, not just simply made them feel better. Nouns are acceptable too if you can think of a noun.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you or your friend did a kindness for another person, as in *acts of random kindness*. (check out https://www.randomactsofkindness.org/)
You acted in an unexpectedly thoughtful way, or you did a small favor that meant a lot to another, kindly act, act of grace, acting with generosity beyond what is required.

Answer (score -1):

[Help out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/help%20out) (Merriam Webster Dictionary)to do something so another person's job or task is easier

[Minister](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minister#English) (Wiktionary) To attend to (the needs of); to tend; to take care (of); to give aid; to give service

Comment: It would be good if downvoter cares to explain the reason for downvoting.